# Working with multiple environments during integration testing with ASP.NET Core

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx, xunit

Here's the launchSettings.json file for the test project:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "test": {
      "commandName": "test",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "Hosting:Environment": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The test project has a dependency on the server project, and initializes the tests using the server project's `Startup` class directly like so:

```
Server = new TestServer(TestServer.CreateBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
Client = Server.CreateClient();
```

Yet for some reason, when I enter the `Startup.Configure` method in the debugger, `env.EnvironmentName` is Production. Where am I supposed to set the environment name for the test .xproj?

On a related note, should I have a local test version of the `Startup` class in the test project? [The docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/testing/unit-testing.html#creating-test-projects) seem to suggest otherwise... And where will the appsettings come from? They don't show the test project as having a copy of the appsettings locally, but I'm pretty sure the `Startup` class (whether reused or local) will need it. Please advise.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the UseEnvironment method.

`Server = new TestServer(TestServer.CreateBuilder().UseEnvironment("Testing").UseStartup<Startup>());`

Answer (score 0):

Using .UseEnvironment("Development") will get you detailed error messages and etc