# Targeting different Profiles during Testing

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I have a `launchsettings.json` file in my ASP.Net Core project with a few different profiles, two of which let me toggle between using SQL Server and Sqlite.

```
"Windows: Dev - Sql Server": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "StorageProvider": "MSSQLServer",
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
"Windows: Dev - Sqlite": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "StorageProvider": "Sqlite",
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
```

I'd like to run my integration tests against both profiles, so that I can make sure my data store provider abstraction layer works properly for both data stores. How would I go about running my integration tests, which are just NUnit tests, under a given profile? I was reading [an existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734681/working-with-multiple-environments-during-integration-testing-with-asp-net-core) answer but it's not applicable to me. I don't want to hard-code my desired profile/environments in the tests. They need to be configurable so that I can run the tests during automated builds.

Thanks